# Spring Data JPA + Hibernate + Log4j2 ClassLoadingException when creating entityManagerFactory Bean

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j, spring-data-jpa

I've been having trouble getting Spring to inject the entityManagerFactory for a project using Spring Data JPA, Hibernate, and log4j. It appears that we're able to receive log messages from hibernate when spring begins to load beans from the context at first. When it attempts to load the entityManagerFactory bean, hibernate isn't able to load the org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ContextMapJsonAttributeConverter. After checking in the jar, the class is actually there at the correct path. I'm using a custom appender, but up until now we this hasn't caused any problems. Any help on this (or even a point in the right direction) would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I'm using log4j**2**, not just log4j, and this problem doesn't occur when running from within eclipse.

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd">


    <!-- Directory to scan for repository classes -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="man.prototype.mid.sen" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>user</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>password</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpaData" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

I recently switched to using log4j instead of an in-house logging app, and chances are this is the root of the problem. Here's the other dependencies from the pom.xml:

```
<properties>

    <!-- Specify the Version for JUnit. -->
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>

    <!-- Specify the Version for each of the packages we use. -->
    <apache.activemq.version>5.3.1</apache.activemq.version>
    <apache.commons.lang.version>3.4</apache.commons.lang.version>
    <apache.commons.collections.version>4.1</apache.commons.collections.version>
    <google.guava.version>19.0</google.guava.version>
    <apache.httpcomponents.version>4.5.1</apache.httpcomponents.version>
    <postgresql.version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</postgresql.version>

    <springframework.jms.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</springframework.jms.version>
       <springframework.boot.version>1.3.3.RELEASE</springframework.boot.version>


</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.commons.lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.httpcomponents.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Routes logs from slf4j to log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>       

    <!-- Google -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${google.guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Spring Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.jms.version}</version>
    </dependency>    

    <!-- Database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Added to backport LocalDateTime (new to Java 8) to dependencies that won't recognize it -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
        <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- This is here for JSON dependencies for hibernate/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Test Dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.43-beta</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.19</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Provide slf4j facade for commons logging (which we excluded in the previous dependency) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.19</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



<!-- Build settings -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- mvn package sonar:sonar -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>manatee.prototype.middleware.sensor.core.SensorMain</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <!-- This transformer is here to concatenate log4j2 cache during fatjar creation  -->
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="com.github.edwgiz.mavenShadePlugin.log4j2CacheTransformer.PluginsCacheFileTransformer">
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.edwgiz</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin.log4j2-cachefile-transformer</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here's the error I get at runtime:

```
LogMessage: id=tbd, eventTimestamp=2016-03-29T10:25:14.054, logTimestamp=tbd, reporter=[org.hibernate.Version], level=INFO, text=[HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}]
LogMessage: id=tbd, eventTimestamp=2016-03-29T10:25:14.055, logTimestamp=tbd, reporter=[org.hibernate.cfg.Environment], level=INFO, text=[HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found]
LogMessage: id=tbd, eventTimestamp=2016-03-29T10:25:14.055, logTimestamp=tbd, reporter=[org.hibernate.cfg.Environment], level=INFO, text=[HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist]
LogMessage: id=tbd, eventTimestamp=2016-03-29T10:25:14.062, logTimestamp=tbd, reporter=[org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceBinding], level=DEBUG, text=[Overriding existing service binding [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccService]]
LogMessage: id=tbd, eventTimestamp=2016-03-29T10:25:14.073, logTimestamp=tbd, reporter=[org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl], level=TRACE, text=[Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.engine.config.spi.ConfigurationService]]
LogMessage: id=tbd, eventTimestamp=2016-03-29T10:25:14.076, logTimestamp=tbd, reporter=[org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl], level=TRACE, text=[Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]]
LogMessage: id=tbd, eventTimestamp=2016-03-29T10:25:14.076, logTimestamp=tbd, reporter=[org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator], level=DEBUG, text=[Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory]
LogMessage: id=tbd, eventTimestamp=2016-03-29T10:25:14.081, logTimestamp=tbd, reporter=[org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version], level=INFO, text=[HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}]
LogMessage: id=tbd, eventTimestamp=2016-03-29T10:25:14.084, logTimestamp=tbd, reporter=[org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl], level=TRACE, text=[Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.spi.CfgXmlAccessService]]
LogMessage: id=tbd, eventTimestamp=2016-03-29T10:25:15.229, logTimestamp=tbd, reporter=[org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory], level=DEBUG, text=[Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#3c3d9b6b': [entityManagerFactory]]
LogMessage: id=tbd, eventTimestamp=2016-03-29T10:25:15.232, logTimestamp=tbd, reporter=[org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext], level=WARN, text=[Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [c:\git\sen\src\main\resources\context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ContextMapJsonAttributeConverter]]
LogMessage: id=tbd, eventTimestamp=2016-03-29T10:25:15.232, logTimestamp=tbd, reporter=[org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory], level=DEBUG, text=[Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@29647f75: defining beans [sysConfig,org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension#0,org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor,emBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor,jpaMappingContext,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,jpaContext,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0]; root of factory hierarchy]
Beans Exception in reading Spring context. See Stack Trace below:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [c:\git\sen\src\main\resources\context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ContextMapJsonAttributeConverter]
```

**Edit 2:** Here is the dependency tree of the project.

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ sen ---
[INFO] man.prototype.mid:sen:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- man.prototype.com:logger:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- man.prototype.com:messaging:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.ini4j:ini4j:jar:0.5.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.11.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4-1206-jdbc42:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.0.43-beta:test
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.2.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.19:runtime
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.19:runtime
```

Comment: there should be stack trace showing where the loading of `ContextMapJsonAttributeConverter` happens, and why it cannot be loaded.  I kind of suspect JPA/Hibernate mistakenly scanned the class to be put under the EMF, but that needs extra configs so scanning failed.  Given you haven't defined packageToScan in LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, I suspect it is defined in persistence.xml and you may tweak on it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the dependency log4j-core.

Comment: Gave it try, even though the custom appender we use will import it anyways. unfortunately it still didn't work. Also tried importing it and log4j-api version 2.5 with no success.